# How do I install Ubuntu (I'm a linux noob)?

Tags: system-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-to-install-ubuntu)

Assuming I know nothing about linux, where do I go to download the installation files, and how do I go about installing it?

Are there certain resources I can read to answer these questions.Bare in mind the context of this question is someone who has only used windows and therefore is not familiar with previous linux installations.